# Restringir acceso por url

Tags: python, django, django-models

en mi aplicacion tengo el modelo user que extiende de AbstractUser y le he agregado dos campos booleanos, mi pregunta es, como puedo hacer que el usuario no ingrese a determinadas vistas por url dependiendo si es validador o es digitador? hasta ahora solo he hecho tales validaciones a nivel de plantilla pero si digito en la barra de direcciones se renderiza el template, seria bueno si puedo hacer que vuelva a la vista anterior.

modelo User:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    creado_por = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
    es_digitador = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text=_('Indica si el usuario tiene permisos de crear y modificar.'),)
    es_validador = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text=_('Indica si el usuario tiene permisos de validar la informacion.'),)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se puede hacer de varias maneras, tambien depende de si estas usando [vistas genéricas](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/) o no.

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied


def my_view(request):
    # esta vista solo la puede ver un digitador
    if request.user.es_digitador:
        return render(request, {}, 'template.html')
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

otra forma de hacerlo sería:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def digitador_check(user):
    return user.es_digitador

@user_passes_test(digitador_check)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Para más documentación puedes ir a la [documentación oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization)
aquí te dejo algunos links donde los he utilizado en algunas de las aplicaciones que he desarrollado y las he subido a [gitlab](http://gitlab.com):

**usando mixins:**

```
class SuperUserRequiredMixin(ProfileMixin, View):
   # clase mixin que se encarga de comprobar si el usuario es superuser o no
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return super(SuperUserRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied


class DashboardView(SuperUserRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    # vista que solo puede ser vista si el usuario es superuser, sino, muestra un error 403 (forbidden)
    template_name = 'account/dashboard.html'
```

[usando Mixins y decorators](https://gitlab.com/ragnarok22/airport/blob/master/account/views.py)

estos ejemplos están para las vistas basadas en clases, creo que el código lo explica todo. Saludos

Comment: Hola @Reinier, estoy usando vistas basadas en clases y me caeria genial el ejemplo, pero las paginas de los enlaces que me diste ya no funcionan

Comment: muy raro porque antes de publicar mi respuesta entre al sitio y puse mis proyectos publicos, de todas formas editaré mi respuesta y añadiré dichos ejemplos

Comment: Pregunta: la clase ProfileMixin viene de la libreria uniauth.base?

Comment: @Reiner ya lo implemente, funciona perfectamente gracias

Comment: @MauricioVilla la clase ProfileMixin es de mi creación